# Which is the suggested place to modify binded form data in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've a form for creating a new `Customer`. A customer may have a mobile number. Mobile number should be persisted without `+` or `00` prefix that user can type. This can be accomplished easly with:

```
$customer->setMobile(preg_replace("/^(\+|00)/", '', $customer->getMobile()));
```

Which is the best place to put this code?

- Inside a `CustomerController` prior to call entity manager and persist the entity. Is this really a matter of a controller in MVC pattern?
- Using a `SanitizeCustomerSubscriber` and listening to `FormEvents:POST_BIND` event
- Using a `CustomerSanitizer` service

Any other idea? Of course i'm speaking of data manipulation in general, mobile number is just an example: fields to be sanitized could be more than just one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should do this in the `PRE_BIND` event, where you can access the submitted data before it is being processed.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    if (isset($data['mobile'])) {
        $data['mobile'] = preg_replace("/^(\+|00)/", '', $data['mobile']);
    }
    $event->setData($data);
});
```

For the record, as of Symfony 2.3, this event is called `PRE_SUBMIT`.

Comment: I have a **registerAction in BookController** that uses similar PRE_SUBMIT event to manipulate form data. I works well. But, after creating a **loginAction in SecurityController** today, whenever I submit login action, it(program control) goes to **PRE_SUBMIT** event created for register action. How to avoid this login action interruption with PRE_SUBMIT event created for register action? **Note:** both controller uses same entity class.

Answer (score 10):

I'd put this into the `Customer` `setMobile()` method — the closer to the data itself, the better. This way the mobile number will be sanitized no matter what controllers or forms are used to set it.

Comment: Besides Bernhard Schussek is Symfony Form maintainer, I think is a lot better (on this case) do it in setMobile() as well.