# Symfony2 insert form value after bind() and before check isValid()

Tags: php, symfony

I want the combination of both fbid and game_id be unique.
I want to test it with the form->isValid() method. But I don't want to pass this values by hidden input.

My entity code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Member",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"fbid", "game_id"})
 *          })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"fbid","game"})
 */
class Member
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="members")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $game;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $fbid;
```

I try:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($request);
    $member = $form->getData();
    $member->setGame( $this->game );
    $form->setData($member);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
```

But I have this problem:

> You cannot change the data of a bound form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you can't check form validity with isValid() if you changed form data after binding..

Why do you need to setGame between binding and validity check ?

You should set associated game before binding your request as following :

```
//For creation, you have to initialize a new object
$member = new Member();
$member->setGame( $this->game );

$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $member)->getForm();

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($member);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return new Response(print_r($errors, true));
    } else {
        // persist entity ...
    }

    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
```

Comment: When i do that, isValid() return true, but i have a "Integrity constraint violation" (game value is not in my form)

Comment: So validate the entity itself after having checked the form. I'm gonna edit the answer...

Comment: fbid come from my form and game value not

Comment: I understand that, that's why you have to validate the entity itself.

Comment: It's strange the value return by `$validator->validate($member)` is too big to do a count on it, or to display it.

Answer (score 3):

**Gremo**'s solution is good one, but it is not good idea to create global service and listen all POST_BIND events just to handle one form POST_BIND. It is much cheaper to set this hook only when specified form created.

Here is my suggestion https://gist.github.com/4167466

Comment: `$data->setSomeAdditionalField('setSomeAdditionalField');` i don't find doc about setSomeAdditionalField?! and how to pass dynamic value to setSomeAdditionalField

Comment: oh, it is used just to show that you can use your entity and set some field of it ($data->setGame, $data->setFbid...)

Comment: Sorry! And how to pass dynamic value 'setSomeAdditionalField'

Comment: What kind of value do you want to bind to?

Answer (score 0):

Make a service and listen to the `FormEvents::POST_BIND` event. In your `onPostBind()` you can get the values to check, and add an error if necessary:

```php
class AddGameValidation implements EventSubscriberInterface
{   
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::POST_BIND => 'onPostBind',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent $event
     */
    public function onPostBind(DataEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // Get the data

        if(false === $condition) {
            $form->addError(new FormError('Some message'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an event subscriber in your form, and listen to the FormEvents::POST_BIND event perhaps.
More on using event subscriber: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

And a similar stackoverflow question: [Which is the suggested place to modify binded form data in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697560/which-is-the-suggested-place-to-modify-binded-form-data-in-symfony)