# symfony2 can I change individual values on editForm after bindRequest?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

This piece of code doesn't do what I intended.

At the last lines there I set a value to the $entity, expecting it to change the value of the editForm that the user gets sent back to after this manual formError has been added.

But I realize that the editForm that the user is faced with is that same editForm that the previous request was already bound to (and that is what you want since other values might have been changed, values that we allow to change).

Now is it possible to set value to the editForm like $editForm->setWidth() or something similar to accomplish what I need?

```
    $originalEntity = clone $entity;

    $editForm   = $this->createForm(new ContainerType($tempCompany), $entity);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $editForm->bind($request);

    //if container is a screen user is not allowed to change resolution
    if ( !$entity->getIsGroup() && ( $entity->getWidth() != $originalEntity->getWidth() || $entity->getHeight() != $originalEntity->getHeight() ) ) {
        $error = new FormError("Eftersom detta är en skärm och ingen grupp tillåts du inte ändra upplösningen, detta kan endast göras av cloudsign support (som konfigurerat skärmen).");
        $editForm->get('width')->addError($error);
        $entity->setWidth($originalEntity->getWidth());
        $entity->setHeight($originalEntity->getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697560/which-is-the-suggested-place-to-modify-binded-form-data-in-symfony

Comment: Not quite what I want, I see you're suggesting a better way for doing the validation. I like to keep the validation where it is for various reasons. Just asking, is there a way to manually set the default VALUE of the FORM fields before render?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a better way for doing validation, the title of the question is "Which is the suggested place to modify binded form data in Symfony?" and Bernhard's answer is right, you can change the form's data before rendering it and after binding the submited data in the PRE_SUBMIT event (btw, start using $form->submit($request)).

Comment: Oh, that's not the title I put, strange..

Answer (score 0):

Use [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). Specifically, the `PRE_SUBMIT` event. You could create a class like `ContainerScreenSubscriber` which extends `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface`

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ContainerScreenSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // do your checks and manipulate the form data here
    }
}
```

In your Form Type

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new ContainerScreenSubscriber());
```

Hope that helps a bit. I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Not quite what I want, I see you're suggesting a better way for doing the validation. I like to keep the validation where it is for various reasons (a o I use values that aren't part of the form data to validate). Just asking, is there a way to manually set the default VALUE of the FORM fields before render?

Comment: Stop copy/pasting this comment and start clarifying your question (or trying our answer).

Comment: There are a few ways to set the default value. The usual way, if it's a new record not yet persisted would be to set a default value on the properties of your entity. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I know, that's the exact feature I want to access, but after binding the request. I need to pull in the form data to validate, and if I find an error in user input I want to send user back to the form with some of the values reset to a default and not preserve in the form those erroneous values the user entered. Can it be done? I can hack it with JavaScript but I rather not